# Creating a class for only one object

Tags: c++, class, oop

I think this is a pretty simple question, but I can't seem to find a good answer for it by googling.

While programming in C++ (as a beginner), I often like to organize my code using classes. But is there a reason to not create a class when I will only need one object for that class? When I learned about object oriented programming, I understood that classes are a way to describe certain *objects* when you need *many* of them.

I guess my question is simply: Is it common to create a class if only one object is needed of that class?

Comment: It depends how you are using it in your code. If it's easier to hide behind the scenes work in a class, then go for it. Otherwise, don't overthink OOP and use it to the extreme.

Comment: I think he's referring to only using the class one time... not allowing only a single instance.

Comment: I mean to make a class of which I create only one object which I use throughout the code/project. In my case I don't really need to "physically" restrict it to only one object even though I will only create one object. But it seems from the answers bellow that Singleton Pattern is what I'm asking about!

Comment: No, the singleton pattern is for restricting the code to make it impossible to create additional objects. If you will ever just *need* one object of the class, just create that one. There is no need to add extra complexity if you don' t have a problem to solve (like accidentally creating multiple copies).

Comment: ah, this is actually the answer I needed the most. Singleton Pattern is just a way of making it impossible to have more than one object. If there is no reason to believe more than one object i created, then fine, create a class and create one object, and that is a common thing to do!

Answer (score 4):

Even if you only need to instantiate an object of a class once, it is beneficial to create a class header file with its own variables and functions rather than defining them in main. Creating a class reinforces the concept of encapsulation, which makes the code more easily maintainable (you can reuse the class and/or update the functionality). Moreover, creating a class will keep the format consistent and make the code easy to read when you re-read it or invite someone to look over your program.

Comment: Yes basically the reason I want to do this, is that I feel my code is more understandable as it grows larger and larger, even if I'm the only one working on it. I just had a feeling I was "overusing" classes in some sense. 
But thanks, at least this clarifies that what I'm doing is not a bad idea:)

Comment: You're welcome! I am also a beginner!

Answer (score 3):

Yes...for various reasons.

1. It might change in the future that you need multiple instances, you will have to rewrite less.
2. You still encapsulate all the needed variables inside the class.
3. Look up the advantages of the singleton pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern . Thread safety is easier to implement for one
4. you don't need to implement the double checked locking pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

C++ offers a nice way to initialize singletons

```
Singleton& instance()
{
     static Singleton s;
     return s;
}
```

No if's required and it is immediately thread safe

Answer (score 2):

> Is it common to create a class if only one object is needed of that class?

Yes. There is a pattern for that. It's called [The Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

There are many questions and answers on SO on the topic as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+is%3Aq+singleton.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I came across Singleton Pattern and understood this was a way of restricting a class to only be able to have one object. I thought it was for very specific cases, but I will give it a closer read.

Comment: Singleton pattern is very controversial so read a lot before using it. I don't see any problem using only one instance of a normal class..(encapsulation...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is also a pattern for this: singleton pattern.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

With this pattern you only can create one object and not more.